SignatureDoesNotMatch issue in Karate framework
I have a request as follow and I when i try executing it, I get a signature mismatch error.
* configure headers = {Content-type: 'application/json', Accept: 'application/json', Signature: 'xyz'}
And path 'path1'
* def requestPayload = read (classpath:path to json ')
And request requestPayload
When method post
Then status 200

I have executed this in postman and it works fine, so I know the signature and payload is correct. I cannot get it to work in Karate framework.Can anyone suggest what is wrong here?
This is my pom.xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-junit5 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-apache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


I tried truncating the spaces, and I tried https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1385, but I got an error that bodyAsString is not recognized. Is there a demo example about signature that I can follow?

sorry, karate-apache is something that is so old and not supported. by the way I have never heard of this "signature mismatch error" so it sounds like something unique to your environment. I think your only option is to figure this out on your own or take the help of the server-side team if possible. no one can help you unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue
